# Refactoring preconditions and postconditions

Tags: ruby, refactoring

Given a Ruby method like this:

```
def create_object_and_do_if_necessary params
   if necessary?
      do_precondition_stuff
   end
   object = create_object params
   if necessary?
      do_postcondition_stuff object
   end
end
```

this code does perhaps smell. Is there a better way of writing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not really. If you want to save on space you can use a one liner:

```
def create_object_and_do_if_necessary params
   do_precondition_stuff if necessary?
   object = create_object params
   do_postcondition_stuff object if necessary?
end
```

Comment: The postcondition code is actually a few lines long, but what I was looking for was if there was a way to just use a single `necessary?`. However, I do think that putting the `if` at the end of the line does improve readability in this abbreviated example.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example extracting the conditions from creating the object.

```
def create_object_and_do_if_necessary(params)
  with_around_conditions { create_object(params) }
end

def with_around_conditions
  do_precondition_stuff if precondition_stuff_necessary?
  object = yield
  do_postcondition_stuff object if postcondition_stuff_necessary?
  object
end
```

Comment: That looks useful, and I think I can tweak it to have both a `with_around_conditions` and `without_around_conditions`.

Answer (score 0):

Given that `necessary?` is a heavy method as you wrote in a comment on Linuxios's answer, the best you can do is to keep a flag of the result of the condition.

```
def create_object_and_do_if_necessary params
  flag = necessary? # which is long or heavy
  do_precondition_stuff if flag
  create_object params
  do_postcondition_stuff object if flag
end
```